# Why does the CompareStringW WinAPI call order small letters before capital letters?

Tags: windows, api, delphi

I use this for string sorting but it sorts "a" before "A". In my opinion the correct solution would be the reverse.

Is it possible to sort like that?

An example of my code:

```
CompareStringW(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NORM_LINGUISTIC_CASING or SORT_STRINGSORT, PChar(Str1), Length(Str1), PChar(Str2), Length(Str2));
```

Comment: Which value does [`GetUserDefaultLCID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlcid) give you? How are `Str1` and `Str2` actually set and what is the actual result of `CompareStringW()`? Let's sort out potential mistakes.

Comment: @AmigoJack I work in Delphi XE2. LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT is a constant defined in Delphi. Str1 is "A", Str2 is "a". CompareStringW returns CSTR_GREATER_THAN.

Comment: I didn't ask you for `LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT`s value (which hopefully is `$08000000`), but to call `GetUserDefaultLCID()` to tell us the result, because yet nobody (including you) knows which locale is actually used. **And again: edit your question to include all that instead of adding comments.**

Comment: @AmigoJack GetUserDefaultLCID gives 1038. I use Hungary/Hungarian locale. But I also tried it with English (US) locale (1033) and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Do you have an example (website, official standard...) where it is really sorted that way, or is it only your opinion/wish? Are you aware of `SORT_HUNGARIAN_TECHNICAL`? Why don't you edit your question to put in all the details?

Comment: @AmigoJack It's just my opinion. For me, logic says that capital letters should be sorted before small letters. That's why I'm confused. Even in ASCII, the code points of capital letters are less than the code points of small letters.

Comment: @AmigoJack "Why don't you edit your question to put in all the details?" I don't see the problem. I've said everything in the question what should have been said. I need a comparer that sorts capital letters before small letters.

Comment: No you didn't - your question nowhere implies you'd be okay with an alternative. And your question title only wants explanation of that one function, not others. While I still investigate why that function works like that to provide a wholesome answer please think about that "_see no problem_" cannot mean there is none, because the downvotes imply others do see problems.

Comment: @AmigoJack I should have asked the "Is there a WinAPI call to sort capital letters before small letters?" - or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

[`CompareStringW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-comparestringw) sorts as per locale, which means unrelated to how big/low a character's mapped value (the [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)) is. I [tried to find generic rules for the German language](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/72231/24042) as example, but sorting lowercase letters before uppercase letters is neither wrong nor correct. In a dictionary you most likely find lowercase words before uppercase words, and so does `CompareStringW()` - not only for German, but for every language/locale where this is ruled as the correct sorting order.

Your expectation that uppercase letters always come first merely stems from legacy treatments to sort characters/[graphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) as per their mapped value: in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) uppercase **latin** letters come first, then lowercase **latin** letters. Looking at other writing systems (i.e. [Greek and Cyrillic) Unicode also defines first the uppercase letters, then the lowercase ones](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=880):

| letter | capital | small |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LATIN H | U+0048 H | U+0068 h |
| GREEK DELTA | U+0394 Δ | U+03B4 δ |
| CYRILLIC ZHE | U+0416 Ж | U+0436 ж |
| ARMENIAN XEH | U+053D Խ | U+056D խ |
| GEORGIAN DON | U+10A3 Ⴃ | U+10D3 დ |
| ROMAN (NUMERAL) FOUR | U+2163 Ⅳ | U+2173 ⅳ |

However, that is irrelevant on how the language itself treats/sees it and it also doesn't account for accented letters (such as `á` and `š`) - the sorting results of `CompareStringW()` are more correct than just looking at the character's values. In numerous languages you want to sort f.e. `Ü` after `U`, not after `Z` (and certainly not after `z`).

In contrast, Delphi's [`CompareStr()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.CompareStr) sorts by just looking at the code points in the old/plain/simple way, so f.e.

- the capital `A` comes before the small `a` and
- the capital `Ü` comes after the small `z`.